# Flash Raspberry pi LED using ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I have a problem trying to get an LED connected to gpio pin 18 on the raspberry pi. I have tested my setup with C and have confirmed thats not the problem, but my assembly code is the problem.

This is the code I have so far:

```
.global main

main:
    SUB SP, SP, #16         @ Create 16 bytes storage
    LDR R0, .addr_file      @ get GPIO Controller addr
    LDR R1, .flags          @ set flag permissions
    BL  open                @ call to get file handle

    STR R0, [SP, #12]       @ File handle number
    LDR R3, [SP, #12]       @ Get File handle
    STR R3, [SP, #0]        @ Store file handle on top stack
    LDR R3, .gpiobase       @ get GPIO_Base address
    STR R3, [SP, #4]        @ store on SP+4
    MOV R0, #0              @ R0=0
    MOV R1, #4096           @ R1=page
    MOV R2, #3              @ R2=3
    MOV R3, #1              @ R3=1 (stdouts)
    BL  mmap                @ call libc fct for mmap

    STR R0, [SP, #16]       @ store virtual mem addr
    LDR R3, [SP, #16]       @ get virtual mem addr

fctsel: 
    ADD R3, R3, #4          @ add 4 for block 1 (GPFSEL1)
    LDR R2, [SP, #16]       @ get virtual mem addr
    ADD R2, R2, #16         @ add 4 for block 1 (GPFSEL1)
    LDR R2, [R2, #0]        @ load R2 with value at R2
    BIC R2, R2, #0b111<<24  @ Bitwise clear of three bits
    STR R2, [R3, #0]        @ Store result in Register [set input]
    LDR R3, [SP, #16]       @ Get virtual mem address
    ADD R3, R3, #4          @ Add 4 for block 1 (GPFSEL1)
    LDR R2, [SP, #16]       @ Get virtual mem addr
    ADD R2, R2, #4          @ add 4 for block 1 (GPFSEL1)
    LDR R2, [R2, #0]        @ Load R2 with value at R2
    ORR R2, R2, #1<<24      @ Set bit....
    STR R2, [R3, #0]        @ ...and make output

on: 
    LDR R3, [SP, #16]       @ get virt mem addr
    MOV R4, #1              @ get 1
    MOV R2, R4, LSL#18      @ Shift by pin number
    STR R2, [R3, #0]        @ write to memory
    LDR R0, [SP, #12]       @ get file handle
    BL  close               @ close file

    ADD SP, SP, #16         @ restore SP

    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0


.addr_file: .word   .file
.flags:     .word   1576962
@.gpiobase: .word   0x20200000  @ GPIO_Base for Pi 1
.gpiobase:  .word   0x3F200000  @ GPIO_Base for Pi 2

.data
.file:  .ascii "/dev/mem\000"
```

I managed to get it working with the GPIO 47 pin. However when I changed it to work with pin 18 this is where I ran into issues. Thanks in advance for any help, its greatly appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to ask you which Raspberry Pi are you using. GPIO pin layout matters and they are all not the same.

Comment: Are you using store/reload (`STR R0, [SP, #16]` / `LDR R3, [SP, #16]`) as some kind of intentional delay?  If not, then *un-optimized* compiler-generated code is not a good example to follow.  It spills/reloads to memory between C statements only to support modifying C variables with a debugger when stopped at breakpoints.  Normal code should just keep variables in registers; ARM has 16 of them, 14 of which are general-purpose.  Anyway, I don't think you need to spill anything to memory, so the only stores should be the actual MMIO writes.

Comment: From a link-only answer: http://enigmater.blogspot.ca/p/blog-page_13.html?m=1 describes the GPIO pins, and might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at BCM2835 documentation - Broadcom BCM2835 ARM Peripherals https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf

Is seems that your code is based on Raspberry Pi, Assembly Language, Bruce Smith.

I'm not why we are clearing the 3 bits since the docs say is sets for input.

*** I confirmed that it works on my RPi 2 B with 3+ volts on the pin.

Target pin = 18
Set GPIO Func:
26-24 FSEL18 FSEL18 - Function Select 18 R/W 0 
Which is in GPIO Alternate function select register 1
So: 0x 7E20 0004 GPFSEL1 GPIO Function Select 1 32 R/W | offset #0x4

```
init_output:                        // init for OUTPUT
            ldr r3, [sp, #8]        // virt GPIO base
            add r3, r3, #0x4        // offset to GPFSEL1
            ldr r2, [r3]            // get contents of GPFSEL1
            orr r2, r2, #0b001<<18  // set 3 bits re FSEL18 output
            str r2, [r3]            // store set bits at GPFSEL1
```

Set Output:
31-0 SETn (n=0..31) 0 = No effect 1 = Set GPIO pin n R/W 0
Which is in GPIO Output Set Register 0 
So: 0x 7E20 001C GPSET0 GPIO Pin Output Set 0 32 W | offset #0x1C == 28

```
set_pin:
        ldr r3, [sp, #8]            // virt GPIO base
        add r3, r3, #0x1C           // GPSET0
        ldr r2, [r3]                // get content of GPSET0
        orr r2, r2, #1<<18          // set PIN 18
        str r2,[r3]                 // set PIN 18 @ GPSET0
```

Clear Output:
31-0 CLRn (n=0..31) 0 = No effect 1 = Clear GPIO pin n R/W 0 
Which is GPIO Output Clear Register 0 
So: 0x 7E20 0028 GPCLR0 GPIO Pin Output Clear 0 32 W | offset #0x28 == 40

```
clear_pin:
        ldr r3, [sp, #8]            // virt GPIO base
        add r3, r3, #0x28           // GPCLR0
        ldr r2, [r3]                // get content of GPCLR0
        orr r2, r2, #1<<18          // set PIN 18
        str r2,[r3]                 // set PIN 18 @ GPCLR0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a revised alternative answer, in C.

The solution as clarified by InfinitelyManic worked fine on a Pi-0 running Stretch. The "set" operation worked fine on a Pi-1B running Jessie (K 4.9.35) or Openelec 8.0.4 = Kodi 17.3 (kernel 4.9.30), but the "clear" operation cleared the pin but hung the system.

I used the assembler code consolidated from fdbdcbc and InfinitelyManic as the prototype for C procedures to do the same thing.  My hope was that the C version might be more portable.  It uses the techniques above to do direct memory control of the pins (doesn't use wiringPi or other libraries, which I couldn't load onto Openelec).  In debugging, I found that setting the SET/CLR register required writing just the one bit that represents the pin to be set/clr; copying and rewriting the register caused the system hang on CLR.

I've commented pretty heavily and reverse-engineered some of the code from assembler to C using standard C include definitions.

The code below works on Pi-0 (Revision code 920093) running Stretch and on a Pi-1B (Revision code 000e) running either Jessie or Openelec.

```
/*  gblink.c
    Procedures to set and clear Raspberry Pi GPIO pins through direct
    memory access rather than through major libraries (such as wiringPi).

    Advantages: speed and portability (requiring no special libraries).
    Disadvantage: limited capability, long-term maintenance, flexibility.

    If running on Pi-2, change ref to gpioBASE to gpioBASE2 in mmap call
    Don't know what to use if Pi-3

    With testing program.
    Compile as
        gcc -o gblink gblink.c
    run as
        sudo gblink <pin number>

    Written by hdtodd, 12 Dec 2017, based on Stack Overflow ARM 
    assembler examples by InfinitelyManic on 10 Mar 2017:
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702056/
      flash-raspberry-pi-led-using-arm-assembly
    Corrected 23 Dec 2017 to write rather than rewrite SET/CLR registers.

    See also: 
      https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define memFile    "/dev/mem"            // memory device for mapping
#define memFlags   O_RDWR | O_SYNC       // flags for opening mem
#define baseGPIO   0x20200000            // GPIO_Base address for Pi 1
#define baseGPIO2  0x3F200000            // GPIO_Base address for Pi 2
#define pinMAX     32                    // max # of GPIO pins we'll support (for simplicity)
#define pinsPerSEL 10                    // 3 bits/field, 10 fields/register in GFSELn's
#define outMask    0b111                 // 3-bit field mask to clear GFSEL register
#define outEnable  0b001                 // 3-bit pattern for GFSEL registers to enable output
#define offsetSET   7                    // word-address offset to GPSET0 word to set pin (0x1c bytes)
#define offsetCLR  10                    // word-address offset to GPCLR0 word to clear pin (0x28 bytes)
typedef enum {false=0, true=~0} boolean;

static uint32_t  *vAddrGPIO;             // mapped address to physical GPIO register base
int       memFH;                         // file handle for /dev/mem 
boolean   alreadyMapped = false;
boolean   keepBlinking = true;
struct sigaction act;                    // catch CNTL-C to terminate cleanly
uint32_t  gpFSEL, fSELn;                 // offset to GPIO Function SELect register for this 
                                         //   pin & Field SEL loc in that register for this pin
boolean   gblinkDebug = false;           // enables printing debug information

// cntlCHandler() triggers end of main loop if a ^C is received on controlling terminal
void cntlCHandler(int sigType) {
  keepBlinking = false;
};

// enableGPIO maps memory to GPIO registers and sets pin 'pinNum' to be an output pin
boolean enableGPIO(int pinNum) {
  if (pinNum < 0 || pinNum > pinMAX-1) {
    printf("[enableGPIO:] Requested pin # %d out of range 0 to %d\n", pinNum, pinMAX-1);
    return false;
  };

  // if we haven't already done it, map GPIO registers to our memory space
  if ( !alreadyMapped ) {
    if ( (memFH = open(memFile,memFlags)) < 0) {
      perror("[?enableGPIO:] Can't open '/dev/mem' file; exiting.  Rerun as root?");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    vAddrGPIO = (uint32_t *)mmap(NULL,getpagesize(),PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,memFH,baseGPIO);
    if (vAddrGPIO == MAP_FAILED) {
      perror("[?enableGPIO:] Can't map to GPIO register addresses; exiting.  Rerun as root?");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    alreadyMapped = true;
  };

  // locate the register and field for this pin and set it for output
  if (gblinkDebug) 
    printf("[enableGPIO] Memory-mapped base address of GPIO register set is vAddrGPIO = %p\n", vAddrGPIO);
  gpFSEL  = pinNum/pinsPerSEL;          // offset to register for this pin
  fSELn   = 3*(pinNum%pinsPerSEL);      // location in register of 3-bit field for this pin
  if (gblinkDebug) {
    printf("[enableGPIO] GPIO pin mapped to GPFSEL%d and 3-bit FSEL field at bit %d in that register.\n", gpFSEL, fSELn);
    printf("[enableGPIO] Will use gpioSEL register at %p\n", (vAddrGPIO+gpFSEL));
  };
  *(vAddrGPIO+gpFSEL) =  ( *(vAddrGPIO+gpFSEL) & ~(outMask<<fSELn)) | (outEnable<<fSELn);
  if (gblinkDebug)
    printf("[enableGPIO] After setting, GPFSEL%d register contents = %x\n", gpFSEL, *(vAddrGPIO+gpFSEL));
  return true;
};

// sets the pin voltage high (+5v)
boolean setOutput(int pinNum) {
  if (pinNum < 0 || pinNum >= pinMAX) {
    printf("[setOutput] Requested pin # %d is outside of allowed range 0 to %d\n", pinNum, pinMAX-1);
    return false;
  };
  if (gblinkDebug)
    printf("[setOutput] Writing to pin field %d at GPIO register address %p\n", pinNum, (vAddrGPIO+offsetSET));
  *(vAddrGPIO+offsetSET) = 1<<pinNum;  // write to "set" bit
  return true;
};

// sets the pin voltage low (+0v)
boolean clrOutput(int pinNum) {
  if (pinNum < 0 || pinNum >= pinMAX) {
    printf("[clrOutput] Requested pin # %d is outside of allowed range 0 to %d\n", pinNum, pinMAX-1);
    return false;
  };
  if (gblinkDebug)
    printf("[clrOutput] Writing to pin field %d at GPIO register address %p\n", pinNum, (vAddrGPIO+offsetCLR));
  *(vAddrGPIO+offsetCLR) = 1<<pinNum; // write to "clr" bit
  return true;
};

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int pinNum;

  // validate arguments and/or provide help
  if ( (argc < 2) || (strcasecmp(argv[1],"-h")==0) || !isdigit(argv[1][0]) ) {
    printf("gblink: program to test direct memory control of GPIO pins by toggling pin voltage high<-->low\n");
    printf("        usage: gblink [ pin number, >=0, <=%d ]\n", pinMAX-1);
    printf("               where pin number is BCM2835 numbering system.  Not GPIO or Pi!\n");
    printf("        Install wiringPi and run 'gpio readall' to see pin map\n");
    printf("        Debug with 'sudo GBLINK_DEBUG=1 gblink <pin number>'\n");
    return;
  };

  // we need to run as root to open and map memory
  if (geteuid() != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[?%s:] Must be run as root.  Try 'sudo %s <pin number>'\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };

  // do we want to provide debugging information along the way?
  if (getenv("GBLINK_DEBUG") != NULL) {
    printf("[gblink:] Debug mode enabled\n");
    gblinkDebug = true;
  };

  // OK, ready to go.  Catch ^C's to exit cleanly
  act.sa_handler = cntlCHandler;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);

  // which pin are we working with?
  pinNum = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (gblinkDebug)
    printf("[gblink:] Using GPIO pin %d\n", pinNum);

  // enable that pin for output
  if ( !enableGPIO(pinNum) ) {
    perror("[gblink:] Can't enable GPIO output.  ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  };

  // until we're told to stop, just keep blinking
  while (keepBlinking) {
    if (gblinkDebug) printf("[gblink:] Turning pin ON\n");
    setOutput(pinNum);
    sleep(2);
    if (gblinkDebug) printf("[gblink:] Turning pin OFF\n");
    clrOutput(pinNum);
    sleep(5);
  };

  /* ^C terminate the loop above and drops into this cleanup code */
  printf("[gblink:] CNTL-C halt.  Clean up and exit.\n");
  if (alreadyMapped) {
    munmap(vAddrGPIO,getpagesize());
    close(memFH);
  };

  return;
};
```

Comment: For better error handling, you could use `perror` instead of `printf` to decode `errno`.  Running as non-root, you'd probably get "bad file handle" because `memFH` would be `-1`.  Of course, using `strace ./a.out` would give you more info, and is the lazy alternative to writing full error detection in simple tools like this :P

Comment: `exit;` doesn't exit your process, but it does compile.  It's the same thing as writing `(void)&exit`, because `exit` is a library function.  I think you want `exit(1);`  You should probably have gotten a warning from `-Wall` about a statement with no effect because you didn't cast it to void.

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  Both suggestions incorporated, and I found the source of the hangs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a small correction is needed to InfinitelyManic's code above.

In the set_pin:/clear_pin: sections, instead of

```
//        ldr r2, [r3]          // get content of GPCLR0                                                                            
//        orr r2, r2, #1<<23    // set PIN 23 to 1 ==> set pin voltage to low
```

I believe the single line to replace them should be

```
    mov r2, #1<<23          // set PIN 23 to 1 ==> set pin voltage to low (clear)
```

before the writing the register with

```
    str r2,[r3]             // set PIN 23 @ GPCLR0
```

That is, write rather than copy and rewrite that register.  (I had wired the current-limited resistor to 23 rather than using pin 18 as InfinitelyManic did.  Adjust your own code accordingly for both SEL and SET/CLR register references.)

This change sets just that one bit in the SET/CLR register (writing the other bits as 0) rather than copying and then rewriting the whole register (which might set other bits again).  I would have thought that it would do no harm to rewrite bits that some other code was managing and had already set, but that's not the case in all models of Raspberry Pi's.  The data sheets are pretty clear about this: writing a 1 into the register slot causes that pin voltage to be set or reset.  What isn't clear is that on different models of Pi, other pins represented in that register may be connected to other hardware, and setting/clearing them again may have unintended consequences in those devices (apparently).

InfinitelyManic's code that copied and rewrote the register worked on a Pi-0 model (Revision code 920093), as did my C translation (earlier post, subsequently edited to this change).  But on a Pi-1B (Revision code 000e), the SET worked but the CLR failed.  Or, rather, CLR reset the voltage to 0 on that pin but also hung the system, forcing a power cycling.

MUCH experimenting led to that one statement -- copying and rewriting vs just writing -- as the source of the problem.  Tested and verified both versions of the code on Pi-0 running Stretch, K 4.9.66+, Pi-1B running Jessie, K 4.9.35, and Pi-1B running Openelec 8.0.4 aka Kodi 17.3, K 4.9.30.  Both forms of the code ran on Pi-0; the copy-and-rewrite version hung both Jessie and Openelec on the Pi-1B.

Comment: I thought ORR(ing) in order to set /clear the target bit would not set/clear  any other bits.

Comment: Writing a 1 into any of the bits in either the SET or CLR register sets the corresponding pin high or low, respectively.  I'd have thought that rewriting the bits, by copying the SET or CLR register, setting the bit to 1 for the pin you wanted to set/clr, and then rewriting the register, would be the way to do it, since you wouldn't be changing anything but the bit/pin you want.  And that seems to work just fine on the Pi-0.  But the Pi-1B seems to be wired a little differently, and rewriting some of the other bits in the CLR register seems to affect other hardware the BCM connects to.

Comment: My device is Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1 running Debian; which technically is BCM2836. I don't think BCM2836 documentation was available/released at the time.  Notwithstanding, my Pi did not suffer a lock up. Good work.