# Inline assembly issue reading filename

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, inline-assembly

Hi i've had an issue with inline C reading the file name properly. The code seems to get down to the final line and then just stops. I've tested by removing the filename after .ascii and then it will get by this line. So i'm guessing my issue is with **\"/dev/mem\000\"\n"** .

```
asm(
   ".addr_file: .word   .file\n"
   ".flags:     .word   1576962\n"
   ".gpiobase:  .word   0x3F200000\n\n"
   ".file:  .ascii \"/dev/mem\\000\"\n"
);
```

The Actual filename i'm trying to add is '/dev/mem\000', its been altered in code to avoid issues with C such as double quotes and '\0' character but this may be the problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are aware that .addr_file, .flags, and .gpiobase, where not previously located under the .data section in your other assembly example. The author was using indirect addressing.

Comment: I'm sorry im confused any chance you can explain what you mean? The code seems to work perfectly fine when its just assembly, but when i turn it into inline assembly problems occur.

Comment: MGordon0405 in your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702056/flash-raspberry-pi-led-using-arm-assembly  '.file:  .ascii "/dev/mem\000"' is under the .data section and the other items (e.g., .addr_file .word .file...) are under the .text section. Frankly, I don't do (or know) inline assembly; therefore, I'm not sure how inline assembly is handling memory layout in your object file.  So, you may need to account for the location of  '.file:  .ascii "/dev/mem\000"' and place it in .data section accordingly.

Comment: I changed this around because for whatever reason ".data" would through up an unexplained error in my code and I can't find any reason for this and no one seemed to be able to explain it.

Comment: Humm... you mean within your inline assembly code vs. pure assembly code - right? What was the error?

Comment: It works fine in pure assembly code, but when I use '.data' with inline assembly code it throws the error ""ERROR: .size expression for 'method name here' does not evaluate to a constant"